# Understanding New Relic's RUM DOM Processing vs Network Time

Tags: newrelic

Regarding the DOM Processing section reported by New Relic, my understanding is that the DOM Processing stopwatch starts (and the Network stopwatch stops) when the first byte of data is received from the server, and thus parsing begins.  When this parsing of the HTML comes across a CSS or js file that needs to be downloaded before it can be parsed, does the time taken to download that file form part of the DOM Processing section reported by New Relic?  Or does that download time get added back to the Network section of the chart?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to visualize how this data is recorded is from this chart:

[image: New Relic Browser Timing]

We can see the network time is the round trip time before *and* after the application processing time measured by the application agent. The network time to and from your application server is aggregated into the network time shown on your overview chart.

As for the DOM Processing time, this measurement begins when the client's browser begins processing the request once it has the HTML to do so.

This Browser agent will measure this time up until the DOMContentReady event.

Some of the events you mention may be happening in the Page Rendering section, but to be sure, you should load a Network (waterfall view) in Chrome to see where these events happen in the context of these events (red and blue vertical lines).